# Computed value vs. specified value in CSS animations

Tags: css, css-animations, specifications, computed-style

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations#Defining_the_animation_sequence_using_keyframes):

> If `from`/`0%` or `to`/`100%` is not specified, the browser starts or finishes the animation using the computed values of all attributes.

In the following example, the `height` property [computed value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/computed_value) is `0px`:

```css
div#parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid teal;
}

div#child {
  background: tan;
  animation: lengthen 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes lengthen {
  to {
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

But the browser uses `height: auto;`, which is the element [specified value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/specified_value), and that's why the animation doesn't work.

Here's something similar on the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#keyframes):

> If a `0%` or `from` keyframe is not specified, then the user agent constructs a `0%` keyframe using the computed values of the properties being animated. If a `100%` or `to` keyframe is not specified, then the user agent constructs a `100%` keyframe using the computed values of the properties being animated.

But if the browser actually added `from {height: 0px;}`, which is the computed value, then the animation would work properly. Isn't it more accurate to use *specified* value instead of *computed* value in the above-mentioned documentation?

Answer (score 0):

MDN has right, because the computed value of height: auto is height: auto. 0px is the **used value**.

According to MDN again:

> However, for some properties (those where percentages are relative to something that may require layout to determine, such as width, margin-right, text-indent, and top), percentage specified values turn into percentage computed values.

Answer (score 0):

MDN is correct, the initial value of height [is actually auto](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#height), the "computed" value that browsers show is the value that special keywords and initial values translate to.

Comment: "the 'computed' value that browsers show is the value that special keywords and initial values translate to." But why should they do that when `auto` and `0px` have different meanings and different effects? Even if that makes sense, isn't it more direct to use "specified value" in the documentation?

Comment: The CSS standard use Specified value > Computed value (calculated before rendering) > Used Value (calculated when rendering). The «computed» tab in your browser show the Used values, not the «computed value» from the CSS doc.